# Grunt build using bower - specify multiple output files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I have used grunt and following is the current structure:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendors.min.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="../file/path.js"></script>
<script src="../file/path2.js"></script>
<script src="../file/path3.js"></script>
<script src="../file/path4.js"></script>
<script src="../file/path5.js"></script>
<script src="../file/path6.js"></script>
<script src="../file/path7.js"></script>
<script src="../file/path8.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

As defined it gives the output file `vendors.min.js`, But  I want to get output files as follows:

`vendors1.min.js`
`vendors2.min.js`
`vendors3.min.js`

Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: Do you use grunt-uglify?

Comment: Yes used, now not used.

Comment: I mean if possible using that I could make a workaround for you

Comment: Ok, reason to remove that form project as I expected I didnt get uglify to the JS. So I removed that and started to using "grunt-closure-compiler".